# Gradle upgrade 7.2 > 7.3 breaks with "The value for this property is final and cannot be changed any further" (with Micronaut plugin?)

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, micronaut

I'm using Micronaut 3.1.3 together with Gradle 7.2 to build my project.

After **switching to Gradle 7.3**, built breaks emitting some context-free error message:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
Executed by Gradle 7.3
- using Java 11.0.13
- using Kotlin 1.5.31
- using Groovy 3.0.9

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '[PROJECT]'.
> The value for this property is final and cannot be changed any further.
```

With `--stacktrace` a very long trace appears. The following excerpt makes me guess
that the problem might lay in the Micronaut plugin:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project '[PROJECT]'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
        [...]
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value for this property is final and cannot be changed any further.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$FinalizedValue.beforeMutate(AbstractProperty.java:489)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.assertCanMutate(AbstractProperty.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.setSupplier(AbstractProperty.java:212)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.set(DefaultProperty.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.useTestFramework(Test.java:979)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.useJUnitPlatform(Test.java:1049)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.useJUnitPlatform(Test.java:1032)
        at io.micronaut.gradle.MicronautLibraryPlugin.lambda$null$1(MicronautLibraryPlugin.java:103)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        [...]
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:201)
        at io.micronaut.gradle.MicronautLibraryPlugin.lambda$apply$4(MicronautLibraryPlugin.java:101)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
        [...]
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
```

Cause "problem occurred configuring root project" I'm not sure which part of my
`build.gradle` raises the problem. So following my first guess regarding Micronaut
plugin, here is an excerpt telling you the list of plugins in use and config of this plugin:

```
plugins {
  id('org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm') version "${kotlinVersion}"
  id('groovy')
  id('org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt') version "${kotlinVersion}"
  id('com.github.johnrengelman.shadow') version '7.+'
  id('io.micronaut.application') version '2.+'
  id('org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen') version "${kotlinVersion}"
  id('com.google.cloud.tools.jib') version '3.+'
  id('org.openapi.generator') version '5.+'
  id('com.heroku.sdk.heroku-gradle') version '2.+'
}

[...]

micronaut {
  runtime('netty')
  testRuntime('spock2')
  processing {
    incremental(true)
    annotations('[PACKAGE]')
  }
}
```

Maybe this gives enough information to tackle down the cause of the problem?
If not please let me know.

Regards

Comment: We're not DE-CIX customer support department and the question doesn't tell why Gradle 7.3 would even be required to build with. I reads: `MicronautLibraryPlugin.java:103` tried to change a `final` value, which is verboten... trying moving that block above the `java` block; if it won't crash the other way around that may work. Or just just downgrade back to 7.2, problem solved.

Comment: Hi Martin, not sure if I get your comment right, but to me it sounds like
* support only certain colleagues,
* if a 3rd-party upgrade breaks, stick with what has worked in the past (regardless of the reason/source of problem).
* Not sure what you recommend regarding movement of blocks: Which block to move above which other block?

Comment: @Christian I totally agree. Your want to know why the update breaks the build, so downgrading **is not** an answer here. Have you tried removing the Micronaut plugin? Does that still throw an error?

Comment: This is being worked on, see https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gradle-plugin/issues/296

Comment: @Christian You did not provide the least reason, why you even build with Gradle 7.3, therefore I'd not bother to support this in any way - this has nothing to do with Spezlwirtschaft... you could have searched or filed on issue on GitHub right away - common sense may suggest, that it's the responsibility of the author.

Comment: @JustInCoding Sole removal of `micronaut` block shown in the code excerpt vanishes mentioned error (but, of course, breaks the build in other regards, e.g. because of missing Spock lib in class path).
@BurtBeckwith Thanks for the link. Error message cited there gives more details regarding possible root cause than my setup does.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue with my Java build and asked for help on gradle slack channel. It found to be a change in Gradle 7.3 behavior.

[This issue contains an explanation of the cause](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18606) and how to fix it.
It helped me to solve the issue with my build: I had `options` defined in one of the test tasks and then `useJUnitPlatform` was applied across all test tasks afterwards using this snippet:

```
tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
  useJUnitPlatform()    // <-- this line was breaking the build
}
```

This broke the build after migrating to Gradle 7.3. Removing `options` solved the problem for me.

Here's [an issue requesting to convert this breaking behavior to a warning](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19058) in Gradle 7.3 and make it a breaking change in 8.0.

Comment: @Jeremy, @Sergei Thanks for links and explanations. As my `build.gradle` does not create/touch Test targets explicitly, it seems that Micronaut plugin has to get adjusted accordingly.

Comment: As explained at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23544, starting with Gradle 8 the actual solution is to remove `useJUnitPlatform()` (as that's the default now, and keeping it causes problems even if you don't use `options`).

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Upgrade to Gradle 7.3.1 brings back successful builds.

Answer (score 1):

This issue of micronuat build failing with [Gradle 7.3](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/release-notes.html) version has been fixed by Gradle team in [Gradle 7.3.1](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/release-notes.html) release . Here is the [issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/19058) raised for the same (which is now fixed) and here is the changelog of [Gradle 7.3.1](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/release-notes.html) mentioning the same.

**Solution**: Not to use the [Gradle 7.3](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/release-notes.html) version, instead upgrade to [Gradle 7.3.1](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/release-notes.html) release or higher.