# Gradle 8: How to set java version at runtime

Tags: java, gradle

Until Gradle 7, I could use the following block in my build script to trigger Gradle to use a specific Java version independently of my runtime JDK (in this case, java11):

```
java {
    toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}
```

And thanks to this block, I could compile my project even with `org.gradle.java.home` pointing at my jdk17 path.

After upgrading to Gradle 8.1.1, I get this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\dev\workspace\foo\bar\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':baz'.
> The value for property 'languageVersion' is final and cannot be changed any further.
```

To make matters worse, the [official Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html) suggests to use my exact snippet to solve this problem, which obviously doesn't work.

I couldn't find any working code snippets apart from setting ´java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11´, which doesn't allow me to compile without first changing `org.gradle.java.home` to point at my jdk11.

Comment: I guess this may lead you to a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939935/gradle-upgrade-7-2-7-3-breaks-with-the-value-for-this-property-is-final-and-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-21 12:31:26 UTC
Revision:     1cf537a851c635c364a4214885f8b9798051175b

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.12 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

I tried your snippet with the following build.gradle and the build was 'Success':

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: My setting is a multi-project build, though. That's probably the issue then. I'll try again from the top-level project (which is just a placeholder)

Comment: I finally could solve my issue - it was due to a gradle plugin being applied beofre the java.toolchain block. Moving the block above the plugin apply solved it!